# Irregular interval Internal Rate of Return

Tags: finance

Does anyone know of a function that has been written that takes a list of cash flows and a list of associated dates and returns the internal rate of return?  In other words a function similar to `CashFlow[]` for irregular intervals.

If not, is there a better way to write one than to create a day-interval list then feed it to `CashFlow[]`?

Comment: From the docs (`Cashflow` page) : Future value at 9% of a stream of cash flows occurring at irregular time intervals: `TimeValue[
 Cashflow[{{2, 100}, {5, 200}, {7.5, 200}, {10, 500}}], .09, 10]` gives `1255.06`. The third syntax variation would apply.

Comment: Thanks, Syed.  You nailed it.

Comment: The following form `Cashflow[{{time1,c1},{time2,c2},..}]` allowes to specify times.